# How to invoke toString method on array of class

Tags: java, arrays, class

I'm currently attempting to write a program that keeps track of employees at a company. I have several classes. My current problem is printing out my array of type `NewWorker`. My classes are as follows:

`NewWorker.java`

```
public class NewWorker extends Person {
    private static int howManyWorkers = 0;
    public int workerNumber;
    private MyDate dateJoiningCompany;
    private float Salary = 0.0f;
    public Manager Supervisor;

    public NewWorker(String name, String date, double salary) {
        super(name);
        ++howManyWorkers; //Add one to total workers
        dateJoiningCompany = new MyDate(date);
        Salary = (float)salary;
        workerNumber = howManyWorkers;
    }
    public NewWorker(String name, String date) {
        super(name);
        ++howManyWorkers;
        dateJoiningCompany = new MyDate(date);
        workerNumber = howManyWorkers;
    }
    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        Salary = (float)salary;
    }
    public void setSupervisor(Manager supervisor) {
        if(supervisor != null) {
            this.Supervisor = supervisor;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("The person you are trying to assign a Supervisor to has no supervisor");
        }
    }
    public static int getHowManyWorkers() {
        return howManyWorkers;
    }
    public Name getSupervisorName() {
        return Supervisor.getPersonName();
    }
    public float getSalary() {
        return Salary;
    }
    public Name toString(NewWorker[] nw) {
        return super.getPersonName();
    }
    public String toString() {
            return ("Worker Number " + workerNumber + " " + super.toString() + " " + "Date Joined Company = " + dateJoiningCompany.toString() 
                    + " " + "Salary = " + Salary);
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return dateJoiningCompany.toString();
    }
}
```

`Person.java`

```
public class Person {
    private Name personName;
    private Person spouse = null;
    public Person(String fullName) {
        personName = new Name(fullName);
    }
    public void setSpouse(Person spouse) {
        this.spouse = spouse;
    }
    public void setSpouse(NewWorker spouse) {
        this.spouse = spouse;
    }

    public String toString() {
        if(spouse !=  null) {
            return ("Name is " + getPersonName().toString() + " Married to " + spouse.getPersonName().toString());
        }
        else {
            return ("Name is " + getPersonName().toString());
        }
    }
    public float getFamilyIncome() {
        if(this instanceof NewWorker) {
            if(this.spouse == null){
                return ((NewWorker)this).getSalary();
            }
            else {
                return ((NewWorker)this).getSalary() + ((NewWorker)this.spouse).getSalary();
            }
        }
        return 0.0f;
    }

    public Name getPersonName() {
        return personName;
    }

    public void setPersonName(Name personName) {
        this.personName = personName;
    }
}
```

`Manager.java`

```
   import java.util.Arrays;

public class Manager extends NewWorker {
    NewWorker[] employeesSupervised = new NewWorker[10];
    private int numWorkersSupervised = 0;

    public Manager(String name, String date, double salary) {
        super(name, date, salary);
    }

    public Manager(String name, String date) {
        super(name, date);
    }

    public double getSalary(double salary) {
        return this.getSalary() + (100 * numWorkersSupervised);
    }

    public void addWorker(NewWorker w) {
        employeesSupervised[numWorkersSupervised] = w;
        numWorkersSupervised++;
    }

    public void deleteWorker(NewWorker w) {
        for(int a = 0; a < numWorkersSupervised; ++a) {
            if(employeesSupervised[a].equals(w)) {
                   int numElements = employeesSupervised.length - ( a + 1 );
                   System.arraycopy( employeesSupervised, a + 1, employeesSupervised, a, numElements);
            }
        }
    }

    public int equals(NewWorker w) {
        if (this == w) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        if(Supervisor != null) {
            return "Employee Number = " + this.workerNumber + " Name is " + this.getPersonName() + " Date joined company = "
                + this.getDate() + " Supervisor is " + this.getSupervisorName() + " Salary = " + getSalary((double)getSalary())
                + " Workers supervised: " + Arrays.toString(employeesSupervised);
        }
        else {
            return "Employee Number = " + this.workerNumber + " Name is " + this.getPersonName() + " Date joined company = "
                    + this.getDate() + " Salary = " + getSalary((double)getSalary());
        }
    }
}
```

So my array is attempting to hold all of the people who the manager is watching/a boss of. So when i run my program with the file

`test.java`

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewWorker w1, w2, w3, w4;
        Manager m1, m2;
        w1 = new NewWorker("Jack Vanier", "01/01/11", 50000.00);
        w2 = new NewWorker("Robert Perry Fletcher", "02/02/02");
        w3 = new NewWorker("Hannah Burdett", "05/05/05");
        w4 = new NewWorker("Mitchell John McDonagh", "12/12/12", 25000.0);

        m1 = new Manager("Sydney Chapados", "11/11/11", 75000);
        m2 = new Manager("Steph Scane", "10/10/01", 80000);

        m1.addWorker(w1);
        m1.addWorker(w2);
        m1.addWorker(w3);
        m2.addWorker(w4);
        m2.addWorker(w1);

        w1.setSpouse(w3);
        w3.setSpouse(w1);

        w2.setSupervisor(m1);
        w1.setSupervisor(m1);
        w4.setSupervisor(m2);
        m2.setSupervisor(m1);

        System.out.println(w1);
        System.out.println(w2);
        System.out.println(w3);
        System.out.println(w4);

        System.out.println(m1);
        System.out.println(m2);
    }

}
```

I get the correct output for the first four (All the workers) but for my managers I can't get it to print out there workers correctly. The two problems are that it prints out the entire employee info (name, date, joined worker number etc.) and I only want it to print ouut the employees name but can't figure out how to do this.

Another problem is that since my array isn't full I get a bunch of nulls at the end because of calling Array.toString(). How can I get rid of these nulls?

Comment: Your implementation of toString() in Manager prints out the entire employee info just change that and you will get different results.

Comment: add the @Override annotation where every you override the toString()

Comment: @MosheRabaev But for my workers (w1 w2, w3 and w4) I need to print out all of their information.Ive seen that around. What exactly does that do? Is it just kind of like an extra comment for people who may be viewing my code?

Comment: Find a copy of the book "Effective Java". It will teach you many essential lessons. Why @Override is important is one of them.

Comment: it's always a good thing to use annotations because it prevents name errors and yeah when people view your code it's more readable

Comment: Note that an array is not usually suitable if you don't intend to fill it up with exactly as many elements as the size you declare it with. You should probably use a `List` instead, specifically an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of this line:

```
NewWorker[] employeesSupervised = new NewWorker[10];
```

You do not have enough elements in the array which is why its outputting `null`

Comment: Yes i am aware of that. I just dont know how to fix that problem. Because that array can have between 0-10 elements in it

Comment: @JackWilliams why dont you use a `setter` to set the number of employees supervised

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the employee name when you print the manager then use you Person implementation of the to string method. 
However to access the super of a super class is not a simple thing you need to store a reference in each relative base class to your super class and then make a call to super.superClass.super.SuperClass.toString() to get to the Person toString()

Comment: I think you misunderstood I want all the Managers info but for the workers under him I want just there names. So when i call `System.out.println(m1)`it prints the managers info and then it prints each workers info. I want it to print the managers info and then just the workers name.

Comment: this is exactly what Im answering

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.toString` isn't suitable here, nor is any out of the box solution. For example you don't seem to want to actually use `toString` in any sense since you just want the names. Here's a solution for Java 8:

```
+ " Workers supervised: " + 
    Arrays.stream(employeesSupervised)
          .filter(Objects::nonNull)
          .map(NewWorker::getPersonName)
          .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```